# RPi2 stuck in boot loop

Tags: boot

My RPi2 was working as an OMV server. Recently I needed to power it off and now it is stuck in a boot loop: it boots, shows many information lines at a very fast pace and reboots.

I tried to reformat SD card, installed multiple distros but nothing helps. The only information I was able to read was something to do with `resolve.conf` and USB not recognized.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use a COM port with USB2COM and record the boot log on another PC. Post it here, so I'll be able to help you further

Comment: hmm there is one small problem though - how to do it? i searched "usb2com record boot" but not a single answer :(

Comment: you need to use usb com port adapter, like [this](https://www.m.nu/images/USB-to-TTL-Serial-Cable-Debug-Console-Cable-for-Raspberry-Pi.jpg)

Comment: This part was pretty clear(sorry for my low precision:( ), my problem is rather what to use to record the boot sequence to a file ? :)

Comment: any terminal client with session recording capability, use at your favour. They all are writing to a dot-txt file after all =)

Comment: thx, I ordered the cable and will post results ASAP :)

Comment: This has happened to me before when the pi was not supplied enough voltage to function properly. Try changing wires, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved, faulty was the power USB port, it works great when powered by GPIO. Thanks @Alexey Vesnin, I would never try to power it that way on my own.